# How to bookmark lines with a certain character in a certain column position (notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm doing some cataloging and I have a few hundred lines beginning with an alphanumeric 6 character string.

the 4th character in said string holds meaning and I need to mark all lines with an E in said position (column 4).

I imagine this takes regex and thats above my paygrade.

example

```
AALE01 =                         # []
AALJ01 =                         # []
AALP01 =                         # []
ABAE01 =                         # []
ABAJ01 =                         # []
ABAP01 =                         # []
ABBEVZ =                         # []
ABBPVZ =                         # []
ABEEG9 =                         # []
ABEPAF =                         # []
ABFE52 =                         # []
ABHE08 =                         # []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I need to mark all lines with an E in said position (column 4).

- Menu "Search" > "Mark"
- Set "Find what" to `^...E`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Mark All"

  [image]

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

Note that Menu "Search" > "Mark All" allows you to select a mark style. Mark styles are configured in Menu > "Settings" > "Style Configurator"

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: thank you very much! that ought to do it